Dimension of a linear subspace invariant under closure.
Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $W \subseteq X$ an $m$-dimensional subspace. Is it true that the topological closure $\overline{W} \subseteq$ is also an $m$-dimensional subspace of $X$ or is it at least finite dimensional? My intuition says that it must be at least $m$-dimensional and it has to be finite, but I can't quite work out the proof. Maybe its already a well known fact?

Are we talking about any topological vector space $X$? Or is the topology norm-induced or somehow more regular? Because if the space is Hausdorff, $W$ is already closed.

Yeah $X$ is actually a normed vector space so $W$ has to be closed. Sorry about that.

But out of cursorily, what if the hypothesis that $X$ is a normed space is removed?

@azuwaterloo: In any Hausdorff topological vector space, finite-dimensional subspaces are closed; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673587/finite-dimensional-subspaces-of-tvses?noredirect=1&lq=1.  If you drop the Hausdorff assumption, it's not true; let $X$ be any nontrivial vector space endowed with the trivial topology, in which the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$, and then every subspace has $X$ as its closure.

Well in this case, since $X$ is a normed vector space and $W$ is a finite dimensional subspace, $W$ must be a finite dimensional normed space and hence closed. So the closure is itself and hence dimension is invariant. Whoops.
